# Scala companion object override method error

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
import org.scalatest._
import Companion._


class Companion {

    print(x)
}

object Companion extends Suite with BeforeAndAfterAll {


  override def beforeAll() {

  }

  private var x:Int = 5

}
```

The issue I'm having is I get an error "Method 'beforeAll' overrides nothing. If I remove `import Companion._` and change `print(x)` to `print(Companion.x)` this fixes the issue.

I'm new to scala and am very confused as to why this is occurring.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move `import Companion._` to the `Companion` class:

```
import org.scalatest._

class Companion {
  import Companion._

  print(x)
}

object Companion extends Suite with BeforeAndAfterAll {
  override def beforeAll() = ???
  private var x:Int = 5
}
```

Otherwise you'd have a cycle of imports: `object Companion` would try to import its own contents.